# How to say.(does array[0] equal secondArray[0] or [1] or [2])

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hey so here is an example of what ive written (in javascript)

```
function checkCardOne(){
 if(animalNums[0].animal.textContent === findArray[0].div.textContent){
     animalNums[0].animal.style.display = "block"
     animalNums[0].animal.classList.add("animate");
     setTimeout(function(){animalNums[0].animal.classList.remove("animate");},1001)
     score += 1
     document.getElementById("scoreP").innerHTML = `Score: ${score}` 
 }
 else if(animalNums[0].animal.textContent === findArray[1].div.textContent){
     animalNums[0].animal.style.display = "block"
     animalNums[0].animal.classList.add("animate");
     setTimeout(function(){animalNums[0].animal.classList.remove("animate");},1001)
     score += 1
     document.getElementById("scoreP").innerHTML = `Score: ${score}` 
 }
 else if(animalNums[0].animal.textContent === findArray[2].div.textContent){
     animalNums[0].animal.style.display = "block"
     animalNums[0].animal.classList.add("animate");
     setTimeout(function(){animalNums[0].animal.classList.remove("animate");},1001)
     score += 1
     document.getElementById("scoreP").innerHTML = `Score: ${score}` 
 }
 else{
     animalNums[0].animal.style.display = "block"
     animalNums[0].animal.classList.add("animate");
     setTimeout(function(){animalNums[0].animal.classList.remove("animate");
     animalNums[0].animal.style.display = "none";},1001
     )
     score -= 1
     document.getElementById("scoreP").innerHTML = `Score: ${score}`
 }
}
```

I want to slim this down as I have 12 of these functions and my js file is over 700 lines long

I want to be able to say : if(animalNums[0].animal.textContent === findArray[0].textContent || findArray[1].textContent || findArray[2].textContent)

All in one line instead of three else if.
Can someone help ive tried afew different things but they haven't worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit of duplicated code here, a lot of which gets executed no matter what your conditionals evaluate to. Seems to me this does the same thing:

```
function checkCardOne() {
  if (
    findArray
      .slice(0, 3)
      .some(elt => elt.div.textContent === animalNums[0].animal.textContent)
  ) {
    score += 1;
  } else {
    score -= 1;
  }

  animalNums[0].animal.style.display = "block";
  animalNums[0].animal.classList.add("animate");
  setTimeout(function() {
    animalNums[0].animal.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 1001);
  document.getElementById("scoreP").innerHTML = `Score: ${score}`;
}
```

I don't know if `findArray` has more than 3 elements, if it doesn't then you can take out the `.slice(0,3)`